# Mobile Edge browser swallows first few pixels of webpage height

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I've noticed a behavior where the mobile Edge browser on Android is eating the first few pixels of height of a webpage, instead covering it with its address bar in a way that you just can't see the content.

This is happening on a project I'm working on, but here is a minimal repro. It's a red box of height 1px, attached to the very top of the page (at least it should be!).

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .box {
            width: 30px;
            height: 1px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In reality, though, when I open this page in the mobile Edge browser on Android, the line is nowhere to be found. I've put up the above code at [my github pages account](https://michaeltontchev.github.io/).

If I inspect the page while connected to my PC and I change the box's margin-top in the inspector, I need to add about 9px of top margin to have it display on the page so it's not covered by the address bar.

That gives? Is this a known bug? Am I doing something stupid?

One may say "just scroll a bit to make the bar go away". Sure, but that doesn't work for websites that are fully stretched out vertically such as to make the address bar and other menu bar remain fixed without coming and going.

Thanks!

Comment: I make a test with your sample code. It works well in Edge Android mobile. You can check the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHqmv.png. I can see the red line on the top left of the browser. Which version of Edge browser are you using? My Edge browser version on Android is 46.06.4.5160.

Comment: @YuZhou I'm running 93.0.961.53 . Are you sure you've updated your version recently...?

Comment: I updated my Edge and now I can reproduce the issue. I suggest that you can provide feedback about this issue by clicking **three-dot icon on the bottom-> Send feedback** in Edge mobile. Edge team will check the feedbacks and improve the product continuously.

Comment: @YuZhou yeah, thanks, I did that and linked them to this page. Thanks for taking the time to repro!

Answer (score 0):

It is because 1px is so small that you cant see the box in mobile

Try adding more CSS.

Margin and Padding just defines how much spacing between elements out side box and inside box.

try this :

your modified code with bigger pixels and navigation-bar(or) addressbar :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .box {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            padding:10px;
            background-color: red;
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
    <h1>Navigation bar</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not the box size. If I give it a margin-top of 20px, I can see it, for example.